# Hibernate criteria query for multiple ON condition while joining

Tags: hibernate-criteria

My query is as below:

```
select a_.*
from table1 a_ inner join table2 b_
on a_.id = b_.id and a_.id2=b_.id2
where b_.name = 'XYZ';
```

I tried criteria as below for the query:

```
Criteria crt = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ABC.class,"a")
         .createAlias("a.id","b",JoinType.INNER_JOIN)
         .add(Restrictions.eq("a.id2", "b.id2"));
crt.add(Restrictions.eq("b.name","XYZ"));
```

But it converts into :

```
select this_.*
from table1 this_ inner join table2 b_ on this_.id=b_.id
where this_.id2=? and b_.name=?
```

and gives null result. That is because , b_.name is "XYZ" but for this_.id2 I dont have any value specifically (i.e the value from other table).
How to write criteria query for multiple conditions in ON.